# Get Path Variables and Query Parameters from a URL in Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, typescript, url, angular-ui-router

I have the following url ,

```
product/example/:example/example1/:example1?query1=:query1&query2=:query2
```

I want to get the values that is specified in the path and query parameters, I have tried this but it retrieves only the path variables not the query params

```
this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.example= params['example'];
  this.example1 = params['example1'];
  this.query1=params['query1'];
  this.query2=params['query2'];
});
```

Is there a way that I can get all 4 values ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `ActivatedRoute`has a property called queryParams, try subscribing to that and not to params. [Example](https://alligator.io/angular/query-parameters/)

Answer (score 3):

```js
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }
    
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(s => {
      console.log(s["id"])
    });

// Other way 
    console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));

  }
```